# Change properties (privilege level) Command Prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I frequently use the Command Prompt to execute some system functions (like iisreset, aspnet_regiis etc) which needs elevated rights.

Every time I start the Command Prompt, I right click on the CP icon Run As Administrator. So I wanted to change the Privilege Level in the properties (tab compatibility) but this is grayed out.

Is there a way to change the privilege level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on a System file.

You could unhide the Administrator account, log into that account, then you don't need to use the "run as admin" on any program, it is done by default.

**EDIT**

Possible Solution:

Right click on cmd shortcut, select Properties, go to shorcut tab, hit advanced button, tick "Run as administrator", hit OK,OK.

Comment: That would be an solution, only I'm connected to a domain. Haven't got enough points to upvote this answer though

Answer (score 5):

You can change the Command Prompt shortcut to always run as Administrator under the Properties sheet → Shortcut tab → Advanced.

[image: picture of Advanced button on properties sheet]

Answer (score 2):

To auto run CMD as admin each time without having to right click and run as admin or create any shortcuts, there is a simple fix for this:

In the registry editor, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` (If there isn't a Layers folder, you'll have to create one).

For the value, make it the full path to command prompt. (i.e. `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` without any quotes) and the data of that value `RUNASADMIN` without quotes.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was looking all over for where this was set.

Comment: This is awesome!